# Object replace with previous object in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm using delegate method to pass `NSMutableDictionary` from one view controller to other.

Here is delegate method :

```
-(void)onClickOrder:(NSMutableDictionary *)dicGetOrder
{
   // Here object is replced by previous object.

    [arrayOrder addObject:dicGetOrder];
}
```

Calling it like :

```
    [delegateOrder onClickOrder:dicOrder];
```

It called my delegate method and add it to my array successful 1st time, but when it called 2nd time, in delegate method object in the array is replaced by the new object before adding to array that coming from view controller.
)

Why this is happening?

**EDIT**

and it works fine when i refresh page.(means pop and push view

Comment: So this is the same dictionary instance every time?  Why are you passing it in an array?  Are there other things being passed?

Comment: yes, im adding data into it.

Comment: Then create an empty dictionary and pass it as soon as you can.  You then just need to add data to the dictionary and find a way to notify the other view controller.  However if you are doing that you may as well pass the data with the notification and drop the dictionary altogether.

Comment: Cann't understand it.means i've to send empty dictionary after calling delegate.

Comment: @DxAndroid, what's the scope of `arrayOrder` ? Where it is declared?

Comment: its alloc in viewDidload.

Comment: @trojanfoe i also called method using Notification but it doing same.

Comment: you mean dicGetOrder is replaced by previous one??

Comment: if i send @{"KEY" : "Yes"} in dicGetOrder 1st time and send @{"KEY" : "NO"}  2nd time, than "Yes"  is replaced by "NO" in arrayOrder before adding dicGetOrder.

Comment: are you initialising your array in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear

Comment: yes im. And it added succesfully first time, but it  happens when im adding 2nd,3rd,....  value to it...

Comment: where you `initialize object` of `arrayOrder`.?